# Laravel - htaccess redirect from www to non-www and from http to https with request uri goes to index.php

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, redirect, https, laravel-5

I've tried several solutions but none of them seem to work. I have a Laravel application(public folder is removed) and i wanted to redirect the user to HTTPS and a non-www version of my website
Here is an example of the action i wanted to accomplish

1. Redirect http://example.com to https://example.com
2. Redirect http://www.example.com to https://example.com
3. Redirect https://www.example.com to https://example.com

I was able to accomplish that using the following code on htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com [R=301,L]
```

Now, since the website has many links, i wanted to redirect the users without losing any text after the domain. Here is an example

1. Redirect https://www.example.com/electronics/laptops/hp  to  https://example.com/electronics/laptops/hp

I tried many variations using $ and request_uri but they keep redirecting to https://example.com/index.php. After searching for answers here, the last thing i tried looked something like this, which yielded the same result

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

This seems to redirect any traffic that comes as https://www.example.com/string1/string2/string3  to https://example.com/index.php

So how can i redirect traffic as intended and which is a better practice. Write two  rules or combine the rules using If statements.

I would like to use htaccess only methods, no middleware.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem

You should put this code on top of .htaccsee file after

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yourdoamin.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC]
```

if you put this after

```
 # Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

your page redirect to yourdomain.com/index.php

Answer (score 0):

To redirect www requests to non-www without losing the path or the query string this is the right format:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If your website is on a server without a reverse proxy, you can easily redirect non-HTTPS requests to HTTPS as following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

In case there is a reverse proxy or a load balancer you need to check the forwarded headers, depending on the proxy configuration (eg. `X-Forwared-Proto`)

Answer (score 0):

Try out this one

```
 # Redirect from http to https

    RewriteEngine on
    # Redirect to HTTPS
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

 # (http://www.example.com/foo will be redirected to http://example.com/foo)

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#  to redirect index.php to the root

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I used your suggestion as is but i get redirected to example.com/index.php (https)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem

You should put this code on top of .htaccsee file after

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yourdoamin.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NC]
```

if you put this after

```
# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

your page redirect to yourdomain.com/index.php

Comment: putting your code right after RewriteEngine On redirects to domain.com/index.php anyway :(

Answer (score 0):

After spending a few hours searching the web and testing different suggestions, I found the solution.

> .htaccess in the public_html

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

> .htaccess in the public folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect to https
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]

    # Redirect to non www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yourdomain.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # This made the trick for me
    # Remove index.php from the url
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]
</IfModule>
```

I hope this will work for others too